# Access 2007 Crosstab Query Expression

Tags: ms-access-2007

Goal: to create a percentage column based off the values of calculated columns.

Here's the SQL code of the Crosstab query:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Master_Calendar.ID) AS CountOfID
SELECT Master_Calendar.Analyst, Count(Master_Calendar.ID) AS [Total Of ID]
FROM Master_Calendar
GROUP BY Master_Calendar.Analyst
PIVOT Master_Calendar.[Current Status];
```

This gives me a crosstab query that displays the amount of entries in the database that are "Completed", "In Process", or "Not Started", sorted by which Analyst they belong to.

What I'm trying to do is add another column to calculate the Percent Complete -- so (Completed / Total of ID) * 100. I tried putting that into an expression in another cell, but it returns with a "[Completed]" not found, even though it gives me it as an option in the Expression Builder.

Am I just naming my variables wrong, or is it not possible to do it this way? Can I reference the total count of the records that contain "Completed" using query code instead of finding out the value using a Pivot table?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use the crosstab query as if it were a table. Add it to the query design window and build the percentage column as you would for a table. Does this suit?

Comment: That's what I tried to do, but I can't get the expression correct/valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    xTab.Analyst,
    [Completed]/([Total of ID]/100) AS [Complete%], 
    [In Process]/([Total of ID]/100) AS [In Process%],
    [Not Started]/([Total of ID]/100) AS [Not Started%]
FROM xTab;
```

Comment: Perfect -- didn't realize I should query a query. Thanks.