# Calculate Percentages In Query - Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, percentage

I'm trying to quantify some things. Here's a sample (simplified of course):

```
tblParent: { Number, Name }
tblChild: { Number, Name, ParentNumber, Criterion }
```

I'd like to count the total number of Children with the same `ParentNumber` (easy using a Group By and a Count(1) ), but the problem is comparing that number with the number of children with the same `ParentNumber` who have `Criterion = "Something"`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT "Criterion = 1" AS CritDesc,
COUNT(1) AS Total,
ParentNumber AS Parent,
( COUNT(1) / (SELECT Total FROM [TotalCountingQuery]) ) AS Percentage
FROM tblChild
WHERE Criterion = 1
GROUP BY ParentNumber;
```

`[TotalCountingQuery]` simply counts all Children with each ParentNumber and puts that total into `Total`

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total FROM tblChild GROUP BY ParentNumber;
```

So I'm trying to use that TOTAL count and figure out how many (as a percentage) have Criterion=1. But since it is using a subquery, the subquery cannot return more than one Total. I need it to return the total for each ParentNumber, to be used in the Percentage calc for each Child having that ParentNumber.

End result should be:

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
CritDesc   |    Total    |   Parent    |   Percentage
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````
Criterion=1|      2      |   45011     |      0.333    // Means there should be 6 Children with 45011 as parent
Criterion=1|      4      |   43255     |       0.9
Criterion=1|      1      |   59056     |      0.44
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

I have several of these queries which I union in a report to produce a full report, grouped by Parent, showing all "Criterion=X" for all Parents. That's working, I just need the above working.

Ideas?

EDIT: My attempt at a join for this purpose:

```
SELECT "Criterion=1" AS CritDesc,
COUNT(c.Number) AS Total,
ParentNumber AS Parent,
COUNT(c.Number)/q.Total AS Percentage
FROM tblChild AS c INNER JOIN tblParent AS q ON c.ParentNumber = q.Number
GROUP BY ParentNumber
```

This throws: `You tried to execute a query ... 'Count(1)/q.Total' as part of an aggregate function`. Adding it to the group-by statement throws `Cannot have aggregate function in GROUP BY`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your subquery has no where clause and thus counts all records, but you can do it without subquery

```
SELECT
    "Criterion = 1" AS CritDesc,
    SUM(IIf(Criterion = 1, 1, 0)) AS NumCrit,
    COUNT(*) AS TotalNum,
    SUM(IIf(Criterion = 1, 1, 0)) / COUNT(*) AS Percentage,
    ParentNumber AS Parent
FROM
    tblChild
GROUP BY
    ParentNumber;
```

Note: I dropped the WHERE-clause. Instead I am counting the records fulfilling the criterion by summing up `1` for `Criterion = 1` and `0` otherwise. This allows me to get the total number per `ParentNumber` at the same time with `Count(*)`.

---

UPDATE

You might want to get results for parents having no children as well. In that case you can use an outer join

```
SELECT
    "Criterion = 1" AS CritDesc,
    SUM(IIf(C.Criterion = 1, 1, 0)) AS NumCrit,
    COUNT(C.Number) AS TotalNumOfChildren,
    SUM(IIf(C.Criterion = 1, 1, 0)) / COUNT(*) AS Percentage,
    P.Number AS Parent
FROM
    tblChild AS C
    LEFT JOIN tblParent AS P
        ON C.ParentNumber = P.Number  
GROUP BY
    P.Number;
```

Note that I get the total number of children with `Count(C.Number)` as `Count(*)` would count records with no children as well and yield `1` in that case. In the percentage calculation, however, I divide by `Count(*)` in order to avoid a division by zero. The result will still be correct in that case, since the sum of records with `Criterion = 1` will be zero.

Comment: This I like.. elegant and one-query. Remou's answer works too, but I think for my purposes (if it works) this will be better. You'll see a checkmark if this works.

Comment: This seems to work. It's easily editable for `Criterion = X`, easy to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are working within MS Access, you can divide by a DCount of parents.

```
Total/DCount("Parent","Table","Parent=" & Parent)
```

You could also create a count query

```
SELECT Parent, Count(Parent) FROM Table GROUP BY Parent
```

And then add both queries to the design grid joining them on Parent.

Comment: I've tried joining them on Parent, but then I run into problems with GROUP BY and not being able to use an aggregate function in it... could you possibly provide a full SQL for the join, I might be missing something simple.

Comment: Have you created each query and saved it? Add the queries, not the tables to the design window.

Comment: I've never been good with the design window, it's being done in SQL views. I've got my [TotalCountingQuery] as above (of course saved). I'll amend my post with the unsuccessful join I have.

Comment: Switch to design view, add both of the queries and drag the join field from one to the other. The sql will be created for you.

Comment: You're thinking I need 3 queries? Okay.. could work since there's no more aggregate functions in the joining query.. Let me give that a try.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123168/access-2007-crosstab-query-expression/11125953#11125953