# MS ACCESS calculate percentage

Tags: ms-access

AS a newcomer I am trying to get my head around MS Access to query

The database is a racing one and in the results I want to find the total times a trainer has a favourite that wins as a percentage.

The trainer has trained 22 favourites and 9 have won.

I have written the SQL to get the 9 won figure but struggling to calculate the percentage of 9/22. What is the calculation to add to the query

[2020].FPos = finishing position & [2020].Favs = Favourite type
Total PerCent ???

===========================

```
SELECT [2020].FPos, [2020].Trainer, [2020].Favs, [2020].Favs
FROM 2020
WHERE ((([2020].FPos)="1") AND (([2020].Trainer) Like "*Eve *") 
AND (([2020].Favs)="Fav"));
```

Comment: What you're probably looking for are [Aggregate Functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sql-aggregate-functions-a810ee71-c1cd-43d7-9c55-8005f1893be5), specifically [this one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/avg-function-8a24e7b2-5483-42ac-835e-907f4341f752).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate Percentages In Query - Access SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329936/calculate-percentages-in-query-access-sql)

Comment: The problem I am having is explained further. I can run these 2 select statements separately and they give a result: SELECT Count(*) AS TotalFavs FROM 2020 WHERE [2020].Trainer Like "*eve *" AND [2020].Favs="Fav"
Gives the  22. .............  Then running SELECT Count(*) AS TotalWins FROM 2020 WHERE [2020].Trainer Like "*eve *" AND [2020].Fpos="1" AND [2020].Favs ="Fav" Gives the 9 answer. How can I combine theses together to do their calculations. Then produce the percentage of TotalWins / TotalFavs * 100 ((9/22) * 100)  .......Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as it might be useful for others

SELECT 2020.Trainer, Count(2020.Favs) AS [Count of Fav with Win]
FROM 2020
GROUP BY 2020.Trainer, 2020.Favs, 2020.FPos
HAVING (((2020.Favs)="Fav") AND ((2020.FPos)="1"));