# Access 2010 Crosstab Query Expression--in One Query

Tags: sql, expression, field, ms-access-2010, crosstab

I would like to add this expression:

```
([2013]/[2012]-1) AS [Change%]
```

As a field to the crosstab query below:

```
TRANSFORM 
      Sum(Data.Spending)
SELECT 
      Data.Category
FROM
      Data
WHERE 
      (((Data.Year)="2012" Or (Data.Year)="2013"))
GROUP BY 
     Data.Category
PIVOT 
     Data.Year;
```

This is solved through using another table in this thread: [Access 2007 Crosstab Query Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123168/access-2007-crosstab-query-expression)

But for my purposes I need to have everything together in one query.

This is because I am writing SQL in another program, http://www.ljzsoft.com/ppt-report.htm, which uses the query to directly access an Access database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have probably discovered, Access won't let us use a Crosstab query as a subquery. If we try to do

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM
    (
        TRANSFORM
```

we get "Syntax error in FROM clause". One workaround is to do all of the aggregations, create the derived (calculated) values, UNION them together, and then "crosstab" that. In your case:

```sql
TRANSFORM Sum(ColValue) AS SumOfColValue
SELECT Category
FROM
    (
            SELECT Category, [Year] AS ColHead, Sum(Spending) AS ColValue
            FROM Data
            WHERE [Year] IN ("2012", "2013")
            GROUP BY Category, [Year]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                curr.Category, 
                "Change%" AS ColHead,
                (curr.SumOfSpending/prev.SumOfSpending-1) AS ColValue
            FROM
                ( 
                    SELECT Category, [Year], Sum(Spending) AS SumOfSpending
                    FROM Data
                    WHERE [Year] IN ("2012", "2013")
                    GROUP BY Category, [Year]
                ) AS curr
                INNER JOIN
                ( 
                    SELECT Category, [Year], Sum(Spending) AS SumOfSpending
                    FROM Data
                    WHERE [Year] IN ("2012", "2013")
                    GROUP BY Category, [Year]
                ) AS prev
                    ON prev.Category = curr.Category
                        AND CLng(prev.[Year]) = (CLng(curr.[Year]) - 1)
    )
GROUP BY Category
PIVOT ColHead
```

which, for my sample data, returns

```
Category   2012  2013  Change%          
---------  ----  ----  -----------------
Category1   123   345   1.80487804878049
Category2   234   456  0.948717948717949
```

If that is too nasty for your liking then you might want to investigate whether your reporting tool supports calculated report fields (e.g., in Crystal Reports I believe they are called "Formula Fields").

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked perfectly :) I am new to the forum and this was an awesome start.